# How can i toggle between divs and deselect the div that is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have an issue my html has some divs beside the price one of the divs alredy has the selection in the html well what i have to do is that in the JS i have to unselected the selected and just be with 1 selected but when i select one the other won't change.

Here's my html

```
<div id="package-container">
  <div class="package-center">
    <p class="green-titles"><b>AVAILABLE PACKAGES:</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="coverage-types">
            <div class="coverage-title-container">
                <p><b>BASIC COVERAGE</b></p>
            </div>
                <p class="coverage-titles"><b>INCLUDES:</b></p>
                    <ul class="coverage-list">
                    <li >
                        <p>CDW</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="firstPackage-confirmation">
                    <div class="selected-package">
                        <img src="./assets/packages/selected.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <p class="coverage-price"><b>$30.98 USD</b></p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coverage-types">
            <div class="coverage-title-container">
                <p><b>BASIC COVERAGE+</b></p>
            </div>
            <p class="coverage-titles"><b>INCLUDES:</b></p>
                <ul class="coverage-list">
                    <li >   <p>CDW</p>  </li>
                    <li >   <p class="extra-space">+1 DRIVER</p>    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="package-confirmation">
                    <div class="unselected-package">

                    </div>
                    <p class="selectedCoverage-price"><b>$30.98 USD</b></p>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="coverage-types">
            <div class="coverage-title-container">
                <p><b>MID COVERAGE</b></p>
            </div>
            <p class="coverage-titles"><b>INCLUDES:</b></p>
            <ul class="coverage-list">
                    <li >   <p>CDW</p>  </li>
                    <li >   <p class="extra-space">+1 DRIVER</p>    </li>
                    <li >   <p>SURCHARGES</p>   </li>
                    <li >   <p>EXT. PROTECTION</p>  </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="package-confirmation">
                    <div class="unselected-package">

                    </div>
                    <p class="selectedCoverage-price"><b>$30.98 USD</b></p>
                </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="coverage-types">
            <div class="coverage-title-container">
                <p><b>MID COVERAGE+ </b></p> 
            </div>
        <p class="coverage-titles"><b>INCLUDES:</b></p>
            <ul class="coverage-list">
                <li >   <p>CDW</p>  </li>
                <li >   <p class="extra-space">+1 DRIVER</p>    </li>
                <li >   <p>SURCHARGES</p>   </li>
                <li >   <p>EXT. PROTECTION</p>  </li>
                <li >   <p>FIRST TANK</p>   </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="package-confirmation">
                <div class="unselected-package">

                </div>
                <p class="selectedCoverage-price"><b>$30.98 USD</b></p>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coverage-types">
        <div class="coverage-title-container">
            <p><b>FULL COVERAGE</b></p>
        </div>
        <p class="coverage-titles"><b>INCLUDES:</b></p>         
            <ul class="coverage-list">
                <li >   <p>CDW</p>  </li>
                <li >   <p class="extra-space">+1 DRIVER</p>    </li>
                <li >   <p>SURCHARGES</p>   </li>
                <li >   <p>EXT. PROTECTION</p>  </li>
                <li >   <p>FIRST TANK</p>   </li>
            </ul>   
            <div class="package-confirmation">
                <div class="unselected-package">

                </div>
                <p class="selectedCoverage-price"><b>$30.98 USD</b></p>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="coverage-types">
        <div class="coverage-title-container">
            <p><b>FULL COVERAGE+</b></p>
        </div>
            <p class="coverage-titles"><b>INCLUDES:</b></p>         
                <ul class="coverage-list">
                    <li >   <p>CDW</p>  </li>
                    <li >   <p class="extra-space">+1 DRIVER</p>    </li>
                    <li >   <p>SURCHARGES</p>   </li>
                    <li >   <p>EXT. PROTECTION</p>  </li>
                    <li >   <p>FIRST TANK</p>   </li>
                    <li >   <p class="extra-space">GPS</p>  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="package-confirmation">
                    <div class="unselected-package">

                    </div>
                    <p class="selectedCoverage-price"><b>$30.98 USD</b></p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here's my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var imagen = $( '<img />' );
    imagen.attr( 'src', './assets/packages/selected.png' );

var secimagen = $('<img />');
    secimagen.attr('src', './assets/payment/checkmark.png' );



$(".unselected-package").on("click",function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected-package");
    $(this).removeClass("unselected-package");

})
$(".selected-package").on("click",function(){
    $(".selected-packages").addClass("unselected-packages");
    $(".selected-packages").removeClass("selected-packages");

});

});
```

Comment: Instead of having two `click` handlers, wouldn't it be easier to just have one that sets `this` to have the `selected-package` class and all other elements to have `selected-package` removed?

Comment: You're referencing the plural of the class `packages`, when it appears you need to reference the singular `package` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having two click handlers, wouldn't it be easier to just have one that sets `this` to have the `selected-package` class and all other elements to have `selected-package` removed? I don't see the need to even define an `unselected-package` class. Isn't that what you get when you take away the `selected-package` class?

Here's a trimmed down example:

```js
$(function(){

 $("div").on("click", function(){
   $("div").removeClass("selected");
   $(this).addClass("selected");
 });

});
```

```css
.selected { background:yellow; }
div {cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Some Div</div>
<div>Some Div</div>
<div>Some Div</div>
<div>Some Div</div>
<div>Some Div</div>
<div>Some Div</div>
```

Comment: Ok but the  `unselected-package` has it's own css if i remove the class i'll be removing the css.

Comment: @Venamus Wouldn't it be correct to say that anything that is unselected reverts back to its original styling? You don't have to remove the actual class `unselected-package`, but you should remove the code that tries to add or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this using only one click listener and here i used classes to your desired div in a good way and I have improved it little bit, here's your working code.

```
<p class="coverage-titles"><b>INCLUDES:</b></p>         
        <ul class="coverage-list">
            <li >   <p>CDW</p>  </li>
            <li >   <p class="extra-space">+1 DRIVER</p>    </li>
            <li >   <p>SURCHARGES</p>   </li>
            <li >   <p>EXT. PROTECTION</p>  </li>
            <li >   <p>FIRST TANK</p>   </li>
        </ul>   
        <div class="package-confirmation">
            <div class="unselected-package">

            </div>
            <p class="selectedCoverage-price"><b>$30.98 USD</b></p>
        </div>

<div class="coverage-types">
    <div class="coverage-title-container">
        <p><b>FULL COVERAGE+</b></p>
    </div>
        <p class="coverage-titles"><b>INCLUDES:</b></p>         
            <ul class="coverage-list">
                <li >   <p>CDW</p>  </li>
                <li >   <p class="extra-space">+1 DRIVER</p>    </li>
                <li >   <p>SURCHARGES</p>   </li>
                <li >   <p>EXT. PROTECTION</p>  </li>
                <li >   <p>FIRST TANK</p>   </li>
                <li >   <p class="extra-space">GPS</p>  </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="package-confirmation">
                    <div class="package">
This is package
                </div>
                    <div class="package">
This is another package
                </div>
                <p class="selectedCoverage-price"><b>$30.98 USD</b></p>
         ``   </div>
    </div>
```

And here is your JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".package").click(function(){
$(".package").removeClass("selected");
$(this).addClass("selected");
});
});
```

Comment: How is this any different than my answer?

Comment: In your answer you set click listener on all div, I used specific div with class name "package" which makes more sense because has other div also in his HTML code. And user can understand better if we solve their problem in their code. This is how it's different than your answer.

Comment: My answer was (as I said) a trimmed down example, but what you've showed is no different that what I did.

Answer (score -1):

Completely agree with Scott, and in addition you've another issue: only the `selected-package` div that exists when "document is ready" will fire at click.
jQuery doesn't know about the new div with this class added. In any case I think you have to put out that function from the `$(document).ready` statement.